# How to style html elements in javascript output in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I have a problem with the code I am writing and need some help. I am trying to style and also attach classes and id's to some html elements. These html elements are javascript outputs. And the javascript code is embedded in a php tag.

I've already tried this in different ways but I am mostly having issues with the quotation marks

```php
<?php
echo '<script>
function newLength{
document.getElementsByClassName('listarea')[0].innerHTML = "<div style='height:auto; width:auto;' class='item' id='bgitem'><span class='pull-right' onclick='myClose(this);'><i class='fa fa-times' style='cursor:pointer'></i></span>";
}
</script>';
?>
```

You'll notice that this code won't run because of the **class**, **id** and **style** options. I know the style can be removed, but the others need to be there. I am using a while loop in php, so the script is different for each loop. What's the best method to handle this situation. I am a beginner so I would really appreciate help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Break out of the PHP block instead of echoing it. Your quotes are messing everything up, and you're not using any variables in there anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\` to escape them:

```
echo '<script>
function newLength{
document.getElementsByClassName(\'listarea\')[0].innerHTML = "<div style=\'height:auto; width:auto;\' class=\'item\' id=\'bgitem\'><span class=\'pull-right\' onclick=\'myClose(this);\'><i class=\'fa fa-times\' style=\'cursor:pointer\'></i></span>";
}
</script>';
```

Btw if you use double quotes for the echo you would only have to escape one before the div

Answer (score 5):

You can just add the script outside of the `<php>` block and have an easier time with quotation problems:

```
<?php
  # do PHP stuff
?>

<script>
  function newLength{
    document.getElementsByClassName('listarea')[0]
      .innerHTML = "<div style='height:auto; width:auto;' class='item' id='bgitem'><span class='pull-right' onclick='myClose(this);'> <i class='fa fa-times' style='cursor:pointer'></i></span>";
  }
</script>;
```

Comment: I'm using a while loop as I said earlier and so, the script cannot be outside the php block

Comment: @MichaelDavid yes, it can. `while(1) { ?> html stuff here <?php }` is perfectly valid syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the code out of the php tag.

```
<?php
//PHP Codes
?>
Your JS / HTML code
<?php
//PHP Codes
?>
```

Comment: Please, clarify the answer, otherwise you'll get downvoted